# div visibility under menu dropdown

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with a menu on the following media query:

```
@media all and (min-device-width: 481px) {
  .flexnav-show {
    margin-top: 0px !important; } }
```

on line 633 in my style sheet.

When the menu folds down, the div #sidebar (line 426)is still visible under the menu. The #sidebar div should be behind the menu as is the #article div, both #article and #sidebar are contained in the #content div. But the #sidebar div is only one of those two whose position is set to fixed.

What should I alter to set the #sidebar div be beyond the menu and still have its position to be fixed? Could this be a z-index issue? This is the [website link](http://gladahundar01.businesscatalyst.com/Index.html).

Thanks
-Sohail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements having `position:fixed` has a higher stacking context than static elements, which is why the sidebar is displayed over the menu. reducing the z-index of the fixed element's container seems to fix the issue

[image]

[What No One Told You About Z-Index](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/) will be worth a read.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, it worked out. I suspected that z-index changed the stacking order, but didn't which div to manipulate. Thanks also for the link. :)

Answer (score 1):

The z-index problem is further up the hierarchy, you need to put a high z-index on the #headerWrapper element.

Not too high as I imagine you'll want modal windows to still sit above the header but probably not much else.